# unable to sign with digital certificate on portal

Tags: server, firefox, java, plugins, javascript

Please help to resolve mention issue we are using Ubuntu 10.04 and we have our internet portal that purpose we require digital certificate.we are using mozila 24.0. that certificate show in Mozilla preferences but if i sign with digital certificate on our internet portal that certificate not show. error is :- No Certificate found .![Digital certificate not detect on portal we are install Java 7.51 on the system, is there any package need to be install on the system related java or any require C++ or any add on please find attach screenshots![Error screenshots for the unable to sign on portal][10]

Answer (score -2):

yesterday I tried hard, but today I loking for any text in the site of my CA Digital Certificate and found the new chain of CA.
I installed in Firefox and now works.
I installed in Chrome, don't work, but I import using the system and works... bad, but works.

I see you later.

Comment: -1 I don't understand what you did or how you did it.

Comment: Mr.David Issue with the ubuntu and need help from you